# Change successful SQL Server Select with JOINS to an Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log file `tblktime` that contains all activity for 'Ourfile'. A second summary table tblktimefst (one record per ourfile) has been created to capture the first occurrence of particular codes in the log file and summarize the 'duration' column between the first record for that ourfile and when it appears in the tblktime log. (The first occurrence of 'LSF' is stored as fstLSFBtime.)

The Select statement that I have written accurately returns the unique id field 'Ourfile' and the correct sum as 'TotDur' that I would like to update back to tblktimefst.fstLSFDurSum

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ktf.ourfile,
    SUM(CASE WHEN kt.btime <= ktf.fstlsfbtime THEN kt.duration ELSE 0 END) AS TotDur
FROM
    tblktime kt
INNER JOIN 
    tblktimefst ktf ON ktf.ourfile = kt.ourfile 
                    AND kt.btime <= ktf.fstLSFBtime
GROUP BY
    ktf.ourfile
```

SQL Server returns:

| Ourfile | TotDur |
| --- | --- |
| 47661 | 48 |
| 50265 | 48 |
| 36453 | 13 |
| 38270 | 54 |
| 39730 | 27 |
| 46156 | 190 |
| 37392 | 46 |
| 51905 | 25 |
| and so on |  |

The column that I'd like to update in tblktimefst is fstLSFDurSum for its unique 'Ourfile' record. I cant get the syntax correct to do so and hope I have provided enough info that someone may be able to assist.

If I can get the syntax correct for this one then I should be able to complete duration summaries between additional codes as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As an aside, the distinct is superfluous since the query already does a group by the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about (untested):

```
UPDATE tblktimefst
SET fstLSFDurSum = TotDur
FROM tblktime t2
INNER JOIN
   (
   select distinct
   ktf.ourfile,
   SUM( CAse when kt.btime <= ktf.fstlsfbtime then kt.duration else 0 end) as TotDur
   from tblktime kt
   Inner JOIN tblktimefst ktf on ktf.ourfile = kt.ourfile and kt.btime <= ktf.fstLSFBtime
   group by ktf.ourfile) x ON x.ourfile = t2.ourfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I received the following when I tried it.      Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: oops, forgot to add `TotDur` after the equal sign.... (updated above)

Comment: Thanks again.  I suspect something is not quite right with the new join. It ran successfully but updated all the tblktimefst records fstLSFDurSum with the same value '1370' .

Comment: Boo Yaa! I reran it replacing FROM tblktime t2 with FROM tblktimefst t2 and it may have done the trick. I have to confirm the data as there is at least one unrelated anomaly to correct.